# Unable to start step function after account move

Tags: amazon-web-services, node.js, step-functions

I recently moved my development account away from my prod one, everything seemed fine except I have a service that runs a lambda to start a step function - not ideal but used to work.

My issue comes in that I am now able to run everything up to and including the execute step function from the npm package provided by aws. I have checked and the account ID is updated in the arn of the step function/machine. I see in my cloudwatch logs that it is timing out after 30 seconds (had a 6 but changed to test).

What are some possible causes of a step function not executing after an account change with no code changes other than the account ID update.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved by updating the subnet to a private subnet which uses a nat gateway instead of a public subnet with an internet gateway. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017329/why-doesnt-my-lambda-function-start-an-execution-on-an-aws-state-machine) SO post lead my in the right direction.